# Как в шаблон функции передать шаблон класса (структуры) C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, struct

Есть шаблон структуры

```
template<typename T>
struct spec
{
    T* values;
    int size = 0;
};
```

Необходимо сделать функцию которая принимает указатель на переменную типа `spec` и изменяет его в ней

```
template<template T>
void _push(spec<T>* st, T val)
{
    st->values = (T*)realloc(st->values, (st->size + 1) * sizeof(T));
    st->values[st->size] = val;
    st->size = st->size + 1;
}
```

Но выдается ошибка `отсутствует список аргументов для параметр шаблона template`

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, что достаточно заменить

```
template<template T>
```

на

```
template<typename T>
```